# Why can’t I short Game Stop right now?

Tags: shorting-securities, volatility

I attempted to put in a small short sell order for GME (since I believe the price is currently way overvalued at >$300), but it said the order could not be performed because there are no available shares to borrow. How can this be? Is it because of the current (volatile) situation with GME? Have brokerages placed temporary restrictions on short selling GameStop? FYI, my brokerage is Schwab.

Comment: In case it goes up to $2000 do you have a spare $1700 in your account?

Comment: For that matter, in case it goes up to $100000 do you have a spare $99700 in your account?

Comment: to your first question yes, to your second, nope.

Comment: `In case it goes up to $2000 do you have a spare $1700 in your account?` It's even worse than that.  At standard Reg T 30% margin maintenance for shorts, a share price increase from $300 to $2,000 would require about $2,150 more margin per share.  And if the broker imposes a stricter margin requirement, even more.

Comment: @S Spring  - Buying options when the implied volatility is 300% to 500% is a fool's game.

Comment: The long put options are as compared to the OP wanting a short stock position. The put option is a known and limited amount of risk.

Comment: @user253751 - `a lot better than selling options, though.` It's not a black and white yes or no answer - what's best depends on what you're trying to accomplish and the level of risk/reward involved.  In general, you're right unless you're trying to acquire the underlying at a better price.  And you can lay off the majority of the risk by selling premium via spreads.  AFAIC, buying options on a 300 to 500% IV is a fool's game - wide spreads, subject to huge loss of premium when IV contracts,  and reduced option delta.  It's definitely swimming upstream.

Comment: Who is selling options and who is trying to acquire the underlying at a better price ? The OP wants a short stock position.

Answer (score 6):

I can't know why *your brokerage*, specifically, disabled shorting, but the reason seems very obvious to me, like common sense.

Nobody knows how high the stock will go, especially not you. A month ago it was about $20, and it certainly wasn't ever going to be $50. But now it's $300. A 15x increase. Are you prepared for another 15x increase, where it goes up to $4500? Will you be able to cover that short?

And don't forget, the *stated intention* of this flash mob is to buy up all the shares so that no short seller can re-buy *at all*. It doesn't matter what the "real" value of the stock is, what matters is how much you have to pay to get one. You may end up *obligated* to buy a share from someone who's like "lol haha f**k you, gimme a million bucks or go f**k yourself". Got a million bucks to spare?

There are already rumours that short sellers won't be able to re-buy at all and that the reason various brokerages and clearinghouses stopped letting people buy the stock is to avoid their own bankruptcy from having to cover these defaulted shorts. (Meta: this section could be deleted if this is unfounded)

Comment: Well if it gets too high then I will be forced to cover my position. It's not a matter of "if I can cover or not". I will have to if the price goes higher than my assets in the account can safely cover.

Comment: @Eric33187 What does covering your position mean? (this is a Socratic question)

Comment: Buying back the amount that you borrowed. fyi I do like your last paragraph...interesting! That could definitely be the reason why they aren't lending them out anymore.

Comment: Gamestop can just issue shares. There is no "squeeze to infinity". At some price, the owner of the stock will just cash in for themselves. AMC already sold more than a billion dollars worth of their stock and are planning on doing that again soon. GME can eat a 2% dilution on their current imaginary price and double their real price pre-bubble as a result. It's in the interest of all their pre-bubble shareholders so they'll just go ahead and do it.

Comment: @DavidKaram the moment Gamestop announces any intention of issuing shares the stock will crash. Reddit will reverse their position and be all "SELL NOW TO F\*\*K GAMESTOP MANAGEMENT". These are just stock market games, nobody *actually* thinks Gamestop has that much value.

Comment: @Eric33187 So what happens if you have problems buying them back? Say, by that point, nobody is selling at all? Or the only sellers want a million dollars? With a normally functioning liquid market (say Apple) you can basically guarantee that someone wants to sell near the current market price. But in this situation?

Comment: @DavidKaram: You're neglecting the fact that the Redditors who bought shares now have voting rights too.  The fact that the pre-bubble shareholders could have approved such a thing, if they had voted on it before the bubble, does not mean that they still can.  They have either sold or had their stock (and the voting rights) borrowed away from them by short-sellers.

Comment: I don't think it's realistically possible to have no one selling GME. And if there are no sellers, the price could not continually increase. I would have had to sell farrrr before the price reached anywhere near a high enough amount that there could theoretically be no more sellers.

Comment: @BenVoigt Realistically none of those redditors will cast a single vote, but I don't know if there's a minimum number of votes required for such an action (not just a percentage)

Comment: Oh, the CEO of MorganS basically said that the squeeze buyers were doing something dumb and were going to get bit. But the CEO didn't explain why.

Comment: @SSpring They know it's dumb. They're going to lose the money they put in... which is grounds for the broker to issue a *warning*, but shouldn't be grounds to block the trade altogether! (Note that the squeeze buyers are *not* the asker. The asker wants to do something *even dumber*)

Comment: The brokers are being required to increase deposits at clearing-houses. Now news articles say that a limiting of the trade size is more severe than an increase in customer margin. But the reason in both cases is for the broker to hold capital requirements at a level they can manage. If an investor doesn't want their trade limited they might try a full-service broker or just pay a call-in fee with a major discount broker.

Comment: The squeeze buyers think they have made a stock into a cryptocurrency. They think it's secure profit but it will not work with a company that has negative cash-flow and a debt-to-equity ratio of 147.

Comment: @SSpring No, I think they just like the stock. /s but actually a lot of them are buying it because "f\*\*k wall street" (f\*\*k Melvin in particular) and it has nothing to do with trying to profit.

Comment: It's not possible to like a company that is six-months away from bankruptcy. The bondholders are short the common stock because the bonds are in trouble. The hedge funds are short the common stock because the bond holders are short. The hedge funds didn't just pick a target but saw the fundamentals. Now that's a general viewpoint in that we have, in the past, seen telecommunications companies, airlines,car makers go bankrupt.

Comment: @SSpring Anything is possible if you're retarded! (not an insult, they really do call themselves that)

Answer (score 3):

It is not a rare thing for shares to become hard to borrow or even non borrowable.  Brokerage firms publish their hard-to-borrow lists daily.

I can't speak for all brokers but mine also lists the number of shares available for borrowing.  It's not a good idea to short the stock if that number is low because the likelihood of getting a forced buy in is higher and that can be somewhat more painful with a stock like GME which has a wide B/A spread.

I don't know what Schwab's restrictions currently are (google for details) but as of yesterday they made GME non marginable (for use as collateral)and  raised the margin requirement on GME stock and options.